# SwiftUI: Menu inside list cell with onTapGesture triggers gesture

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a SwiftUI `List` on iOS14.3 (Xcode12.3) and inside it's cells I want to have a `Menu` popup up when the user is tapping on a button. Additionally these cells have an `onTapGesture` and the problem is that this gesture is also triggered when the menu button is pressed.

**Example:**

```
List {
    HStack {
        Text("Cell content")
        Spacer()
        // Triggers also onTapGesture of cell
        Menu(content: {
            Button(action: { }) {
                Text("Menu Item 1")
                Image(systemName: "command")
            }
            Button(action: { }) {
                Text("Menu Item 2")
                Image(systemName: "option")
            }
            Button(action: { }) {
                Text("Menu Item 3")
                Image(systemName: "shift")
            }
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .padding()
        }
    }
    .background(Color(.systemBackground))
    .onTapGesture {
        print("Cell tapped")
    }
}
```

If you tap on the ellipsis image, the menu opens but also `"Cell tapped"` will be printed to the console. This is a problem for me, because in my real world example I am collapsing the cell within the tap gesture and of course I don't want that to happen when the user presses the menu button.

I found out, that when I long press on the button the gesture won't be triggered. But this is not acceptable UX in my opinion, took me a while to find that out for my self.

I also noticed, when I replace the `Menu` with a regular `Button`, then the cells gesture is not triggered while pressing (only with `BorderlessButtonStyle` or `PlainButtonStyle`, otherwise he is not active at all). But I don't know how to open a Menu from it's action.

```
List {
    HStack {
        Text("Cell content")
        Spacer()
        // Does not trigger cells onTapGesture, but how to open Menu from action?
        Button(action: { print("Button tapped") }) {
            Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .padding()
        }
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
    }
    .background(Color(.systemBackground))
    .onTapGesture {
        print("Cell tapped")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it iOS or macOS project?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's on iOS14.3 with Xcode 12.3

Comment: I've tested it also on macOS now and there the cells gesture is not triggered when opening the menu. Even though the menu look very different on mac (it's actually a DropDown), I would expect the same behavior on both platforms. So I've just reported a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alternatively, you can override Menu `onTapGesture`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            HStack {
                Text("Cell content")
                Spacer()
                Menu(content: {
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Text("Menu Item 1")
                        Image(systemName: "command")
                    }
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Text("Menu Item 2")
                        Image(systemName: "option")
                    }
                    Button(action: {}) {
                        Text("Menu Item 3")
                        Image(systemName: "shift")
                    }
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .padding()
                }
                .onTapGesture {} // override here
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Cell tapped")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, there's no need to use `.background(Color(.systemBackground))` to tap on spacers. This is not really flexible - what if you want change background color?

You can use `contentShape` instead:

```
.contentShape(Rectangle())
```

Comment: Thank you, although I think @Asperi answer is a bit more elegant and probably more future proof, I will mark this as the accepted answer. In fact, in my real-world example, the cell is significantly more complex and the menu button is not the last subview on the right side. The main problem is though, that i am reusing this cell on different places in my app and want to have different onTapGestures depending where it's used, so i will apply that gesture outside the cells body. Under these circumstances your solution is much better.

Comment: Other than that, thanks for the hint with contentShape instead of background to make the spacers tapable. Didn't know that, i am still new to SwftUI working on my first bigger app using it.

Comment: This answer no longer seem to work on iOS 15.5 (at least). Worse: the result is random (sometimes you get double taps and sometimes you don’t). Anyone else seeing this? Alternative?!

Comment: Thank you very much, overriding .onTapGesture for menu works well, it's a miracle!

Comment: I've the same problem than @Arshia mentioned. I think the problem is that the menu is presented and when you tap on a "blank" are do dismiss the menu the .onTapGesture of the cell is triggered and a new View cannot be presented on top of the menu that is already on screen. I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is a bug or expected behavior, but instead of fighting with it I would recommend to avoid such overlapping (because even with success today it might stop working on different systems/updates).

Here is possible solution (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

```
    List {
        HStack {

            // row content area  
            HStack {
                Text("Cell content")
                Spacer()
            }
            .background(Color(.systemBackground)) // for tap on spacer area
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Cell tapped")
            }

            // menu area
            Menu(content: {
                Button(action: { }) {
                    Text("Menu Item 1")
                    Image(systemName: "command")
                }
                Button(action: { }) {
                    Text("Menu Item 2")
                    Image(systemName: "option")
                }
                Button(action: { }) {
                    Text("Menu Item 3")
                    Image(systemName: "shift")
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this of course also solves the problem and is maybe the more elegant and future proof solution, but I accepted @pawello2222 answer. See my comment on his answer for the reason.